# Filtro com TypeScript

Tags: array, typescript, filtro

Tenho o seguinte código :

```
search(evento){
this.str = evento.target.value;
console.log('str ',this.str)

this.cartoes.forEach(element => {
if(element.codigo.search(this.str) !== -1 && this.cartoesFiltro.length === 0){
  this.cartoesFiltro.push({
    idtag: element.idtag,  
    codigo: element.codigo,
    alocada: element.alocada,
    nome: element.nome
  })      
  console.log('cartoesFiltro ',this.cartoesFiltro);      

  //this.idProcura = element.idtag;
  //console.log('aqui',this.idProcura);      
}
if(element.codigo.search(this.str) !== -1 && this.cartoesFiltro.length !== 0 ){
  this.cartoesFiltro.forEach(dado => {
    if (dado.idtag === element.idtag){
      console.log('existe')
    }
    else{
      this.cartoesFiltro.push({
        idtag: element.idtag,  
        codigo: element.codigo,
        alocada: element.alocada,
        nome: element.nome
      })
    }
  });
   //this.cartoesFiltro = [];
   //console.log('aqui ',this.cartoesFiltro)
}
if(element.codigo.search(this.str) === -1 && this.cartoesFiltro === 0){
  console.log('nachou');
  this.cartoesFiltro = [];
}
if (this.str === ''){
  console.log('ndeu');
  this.cartoesFiltro = [];
  console.log('cartoesFiltro ',this.cartoesFiltro);

}
}
```

Teoricamente ele deveria pesquisar algo em um array, e se encontrar inserir em um segundo array. Mas ele ta inserindo o mesmo mais de uma vez, como posso resolver ?

Answer (score 0):

Divide isto em "stages":
- Primeiro, encontrar os elementos que têm o codigo que queres
- Segundo, ao iterar sob os encontrados E se esse ele não estiver ja
   filtrado, então manda-o para uma nova array
- no fim mostra o resultado da array com os items filtrados.

```
search(evento) {
  if (!evento || !evento.target || !evento.target.value) return;
  this.str = evento.target.value;

  // primeiro, procura-se os codigos
  const comCodigo = this.cartoes.filter(ele => ele.codigo.includes(this.str));

  // depois iteramos sob os achados, e se ele não for encontrado dentro dos filtrados, faz push para lá
  comCodigo.forEach(ele => {
    if (!this.cartoesFiltro.find(_ele => _ele.idtag === ele.idtag)) 
      this.cartoesFiltrados.push(ele)
  })

  // por fim, retorna o que foi encontrado
  return this.cartoesFiltro;
}
```

[repl.it session](https://repl.it/@moshmage/CoarseDirtyQuery)

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia,

Para resolver o seu  problema acredito que poderia ser feito da seguinte maneira:

```
this.cartoesFiltro = this.cartoes; // apenas para manter o original sem 

this.cartoesFiltro  =this.cartoesFiltro.filter(x=>x.idtag.indexOf(element.idtag)); // Aqui vai pegar todos que contem esse filto
```

Se quiser uma pesquisa em tempo real, no HTML utilize o `[(ngModel)] = "filtro"` e faça esse método no SET da variável.

Acredito que isso irá resolver o seu problema.